# Calculating dates ( with limited tools)

Tags: c, nested, nested-loops

I'm trying go calculate difference between two dates, for homework.
Only problem is we can't use anything outside of for while if loops.. which is driving me crazy. I tried writing the sudocode for it and it seems simple enough but when I start sitting down and coding I get lost when the months start coming in.(excluding leap years)

Say the start dates is July 3 2015 going to March 5 2016.

I was originaly going to add days until the current month is finish and pretty much calculate everything from days. But I get kinda lost when I start including different days for each month.

Comment: Try something. When it goes tits up, post the code here, and we'll try to help you work out what went wrong.

Comment: Hint: you shouldn't need any while loops. This calculation is pure arithmetic in a fixed number of steps.

Comment: One other hint: Consider Julian dates

Answer (score 0):

An idea to work out how far you can go in that month might be

```
for(day=1;day<=days_in_month(month);day++){
    counter++;
}
```

Then have a days_in_month function, that returns, using a few if statements.  If you have a bit of google I remember seeing a few good statements to efficiently work this out - if you need to include leap years you'll obviously need to pass the year to the days_in_month function. 
Oviously you'll need the above loop nested some other ones.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Write a function to convert a date into a "day number since epoc", which takes into account things like leap years, etc. The epoc could probably be "1/1/1970". It'd be easy to just use lookup tables - one for "days in previous years" that includes a leap year flag and one for "days in previous months" for non-leap years (where if the leap year flag from the previous table is set and the month is after February, you add a day). Then you'd add "days in previous years", "days in previous months" and the day of the month to get "day number since epoc".

Step 2: Convert both dates into "day number since epoc" integers and subtract.

Note: The lecturer might expect you to use calculations rather than using lookup tables. In this case, use lookup tables to get it working, then replace the lookup tables one at a time.